# How can i change Hector Slam Map scale and color?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector, hector-slam, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to change bellow parameter to Hector Salam map, How can i do that?

```
FILENAME: DARK BLUE (RGB: 0, 44, 207) TEXT For example, “RoboCup2009-TeamName-Prelim1.tiff” displayed in the upper left corner to identify the map, make it sort properly in a directory, and findable on a computer.

MAP SCALE: DARK BLUE (RGB: 0, 50, 140) TEXT AND EXACTLY 1 METER LONG LINE Display this in the upper right corner to indicate the scale of the map.

MAP ORIENTATION: DARK BLUE (RGB: 0, 50, 140) TEXT (“X” AND “Y”) AND ABOUT 50 cm LONG ARROWS Display this next to the map scale. It gives the orientation for the victim location in the victim file. Must be a right-handed coordinate system: X points upwards, Y to the left.

UNEXPLORED AREA GRID: LIGHT/DARK GREY (RGB: 226, 226, 227/RGB: 237, 237, 238) CHECKERBOARD WITH 100CM SQAURES This solid checkerboard pattern should show the unexplored area and provide scale on all sides of the mapped area. It should also print in black and white without ambiguity with other areas potentially turned grey in the process.

EXPLORED AREA GRID: BLACK (RGB: 190,190,191) GRID WITH 50CM GRID AND ABOUT 1 CM THICK LINES (use a one pixel line in the map) This grid should only appear in the explored area, behind any walls, victim locations, or other information. The grid should be aligned with the checkerboard pattern of the unexplored area, but twice as fine to allow visual inspection of wall alignments.

INITIAL ROBOT POSITION: YELLOW (RGB: 255, 200, 0) ARROW This should mark the initial pose of the robot and always be pointed toward the top of the map.

WALLS AND OBSTACLES: DARK BLUE (RGB: 0, 40, 120) FEATURES This should indicate the walls and other obstacles in the environment. The color should make the walls stand out from everything else.

SEARCHED AREA: WHITE CONFIDENCE GRADIENT (RGB: 128, 128, 128 to RGB: 255, 255, 255) This should be based on the confidence that the area is really free. It should produce a clean white when seen as free by all measurements and nearly untouched when undecided, that is, nearly equally seen as occupied as free, to produce a dither effect.

CLEARED AREA: LIGHT GREEN CONFIDENCE GRADIENT (RGB: 180, 230, 180 to RGB: 130, 230, 130) This should be based on a history of 1-50 scans to show the area cleared of victims with confidence. This should also factor in the actual field of view and range of onboard victim sensors – noting that victim sensors don’t typically see through walls!

VICTIM LOCATION: SOLID RED (RGB: 240, 10, 10) CIRCLE WITH ABOUT 35CM DIAM CONTAINING WHITE (RGB) TEXT “#” This should show the locations of victims with a victim identification number such as “1” in the order they were found. Additional information about this victim should be in the victim file noted below.

HAZARD LOCATION: SOLID ORANGE (RGB: 255, 100, 30) DIAMOND WITH ABOUT 30CM SIDES CONTAINING WHITE (RGB) TEXT “#” This should show the locations of hazards with an identification number such as “1” in the order they were found. Additional information about this hazard should be in the hazard file noted below.

QR CODE LOCATION: SOLID BLUE (RGB: 10, 10, 240) CIRCLE WITH ABOUT 35CM DIAM CONTAINING WHITE (RGB) TEXT “#” This should show the locations of QR codes with the QR code number such as “1” in the order they were found. The details about the QR code (such as the text coded in the pattern) must also be listed in the CSV-file.

ROBOT PATH: MAGENTA (RGB: 120, 0, 140) LINE ABOUT 2 CM THICK This should show the robot path.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126096/how-can-i-change-hector-slam-map-scale-and-color?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RoboCup Rescue compliant GeoTiff map generation is performed in using the [hector_geotiff](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_geotiff) package. If you want to change colors used you'll have to look into the source code itself.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1